# Передача динамического массива в функцию через указатель

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы

Слышала, что массив можно передавать в функцию в виде указателя.

Откуда можно взять этот указатель? И как потом через него получать доступ к элементам исходного массива?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Вас интересует это?

```
int func(int * arr, int n)
{
    ...
}

...

int * array = new int[20];
func(array,20);
```

Если нет - сформулируйте свой вопрос поточнее...

Answer (score 1):

Когда говорят про передачу массива в виде указателя, на самом деле подразумевают передачу пары «указатель на первый элемент массива — количество элементов массива»:

```
int func(int* base, size_t count)
{
    // ...
}
```

Доступ же к элементам производится, как и в случае обычных массивов, через индексацию (при этом мы притворяемся, что указатель `base` — это и есть сам массив):

```
int item = base[i];
```

Данный фокус работает, потому что переменные-массивы — это на самом деле замаскированные указатели на участки фиксированного размера с данными этого массива. То есть никакой технической разницы между массивом и указателем на его первый элемент нет.

Теперь о том, почему мы передаём количество элементов (параметр `count`). Дело в том, что пока мы работаем с *переменной-массивом*, компилятор знает его размер и может в любой момент предоставить его нам (через `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`). Однако, как только мы начинаем работать с *указателями*, всякая информация о массиве теряется, а потому мы должны передавать её явно, вместе с указателем. При создании же динамического массива мы сразу же получаем указатель, а потому вынуждены хранить и передавать количество его элементов явно.

Количество же нужно только для того, чтобы проверять, не обращаемся ли мы за пределы массива.