# Перенос массива из одной функции в другую в Си

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Есть две функции. Надо реализовать передачу массива из одной функции в другую. Сам я пробовал реализовать, но без понятия как это сделать.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int local(int*mass, int g, int size)
{
    while (1)
    {

        printf("%d", mass[g]);
        int* massiv;
        massiv = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
        int k = 0;
        while (k != size)
        {
            printf("%d", mass[k]);    //пытаюсь передать все значения в другой массив
            k++;
        }
        printf("O");    //проверяю как передался массив
        int loc = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (mass[i] > mass[i - 1] && mass[i] > mass[i + 1]) {
                loc++;   //считает локальные максимумы
            }
        }
        printf("%d", loc);
        printf("\n");
        break;
    }
}

int mass()   //Создает массив
{
    int* mass;
    int size;
    printf("Введите размер массива: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &size);
    mass = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    printf("Введите массив: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &mass[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int g = 0; g < size; g++)
    {
        printf("%d ", mass[g]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        local(mass, i, size);    //передает массив в другую функцию
    }
    
}
```

вывод:

```
Введите размер массива: 3
Введите массив: 3 4 5

3 4 5
3345O1
4345O1
5345O1
```

и сразу ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я не понимаю что делаю не так.

как я понял, массив так то нельзя передать в другую функцию, можно лишь один элемент из него передать. думал с помощью перебора получиться, но он его несколько раз копирует

Comment: изучите тему, как передавать массив через указатель

Comment: Вы бы сформулировали, что должна делать ваша программа, потому что по неверному коду восстановить верный, не зная, что он должен делать — задача еще та...

Comment: @Harry Программа должна находить и считать локальные максимумы. Но суть не в этом, так как я смогу это сделать и сам. Мне надо понять как передавать массив в другую функцию, но я не понимаю как это делать

Comment: Передавать его как указатель на первый элемент + размер. Как вы и делаете. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/740291/195342 Не хочу закрывать вопрос как дубликат, но очень тянет :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача динамического массива в функцию через указатель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740291/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Comment: В результате вы спрашиваете не то, что вас интересует. Вопрос следовало бы исправить.

Comment: @Mikhailo А как тогда лучше спросить? Просто то, как я понимаю вопрос, так я и спросил. К тому же DmitryK понял мой вопрос так, как я сам его понимаю

Comment: У вас получился вопрос, почему у меня вот такое сообщение об ошибке? И как попытка ответа - наверное, оно связано с неправильной передачей массива в функцию (которое у вас правильное, только зачем-то еще и с индексом, но сам массив передан верно - указатель и размер).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для передачи массива в функцию нужно передать указатель на массив и  размер массива. И передавать индекс из цикла скорее всего вам тоже не нужно.

```
int mass()   //Создает массив
{
    int* mass;
    int size;
    mass = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
// неправильно - никакой цикл не нужен
//    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
//    {
//        local(mass, i, size);    //передает массив в другую функцию
//    }
    
// нужно один раз передать указатель на массив и  размер массива
// вот так:
     local(mass, i, size);    //передает массив в другую функцию

// индекс из цикла скорее всего тоже не нужен
     local(mass, size);    //передает массив в другую функцию

}


int local(int* mass, int g, int size)
{
// а вот здесь вы никуда ничего не передаете, а просто распечатываете массив
        int k = 0;
        while (k != size)
        {
            printf("%d", mass[k]); //пытаюсь передать все значения в другой массив
            k++;
        }
}
```

А локальные максимумы вы считаете неправильно - выходите за пределы массива.

Comment: Я ранее уже писал другому человеку, что код не мой, а одногруппника. Он попросил меня помочь. И вовремя помощи я столкнулся с той же проблемой, что и в своей другой работе, по этому я еще не успел скорректировать все недочеты его. Сейчас изменю код, чтобы проверить как будет. Массив massiv нужен для другой задачи, а именно для внедрения всех локальных максимумов в него из общего массива, с  последующем выводом его в командную строку

Comment: Спасибо, теперь он спокойно передается в другую функцию. Но осталась теперь только убрать ошибку, которая высвечиватся(см. фото)

Comment: я понял в чем ошибка была. Еще раз спасибо за то, что помогли